# How can I fix an automatic email reminder issue

Tags: excel, vba

The code is asking me who to send this to, but the purpose of the email would be to send it to multiple people at a time. The problem in the code is ".send". I need the code to send it automatically without having to manually input each email within the code.

The first thing I tried was being specific to who I wanted the email to be send with in the code itself. It did not work.

```
Sub SendReminderMail()
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim MailDest As String
    Dim StrFrom As String
    Dim StrTo As String

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutLookMailItem
        MailDest = ""
        For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(4))
            If MailDest = "" And Cells(iCounter, 8).Offset(0, -1) = "Send Reminder" Then
                MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 8).Value
            ElseIf MailDest <> "" And Cells(iCounter, 8).Offset(0, -1) = "send Reminder" Then
                MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 8).Value
            End If
        Next iCounter
        .BCC = MailDest
        .Subject = "FYI"
        .Body = "Reminder: The patient is overdue please contact the patient to reschedule. Please ignore if appointment has been made."
        .Send
    End With
    Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
    Set OutLookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The error I get is "run-time error 462" stating the remote machine does not exist.

Comment: And does it work without VBA, when you try to send it manually?

Comment: @z32a7ul Yes it does, now the error appearing is asking who to send it to, but I already inputted the email that should be sent to.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code (moved variable declarations directly before initialization, changed Integer to Long, reordered the statements to group the ones related to Outlook together, and removed the superfluous Settings to Nothing).

```
Sub SendReminderMail()
    Dim MailDest As String: MailDest = vbNullString
    Dim iCounter As Long: For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(4))
        If MailDest = "" And Cells(iCounter, 8).Offset(0, -1) = "Send Reminder" Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 8).Value
        ElseIf MailDest <> "" And Cells(iCounter, 8).Offset(0, -1) = "Send Reminder" Then
            MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 8).Value
        End If
    Next iCounter

    Dim OutLookApp As Object: Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object: Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutLookMailItem
        .BCC = MailDest
        .Subject = "FYI"
        .Body = "Reminder: The patient is overdue please contact the patient to reschedule. Please ignore if appointment has been made."
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

However, I don't think that these changes would correct the error.

I found in Microsoft's Knowledge Base an article regarding this issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/189618/you-may-receive-the-run-time-error-2147023174-800706ba-error-message-o

To summarize it quickly: If you use unqualified references to refer to variables (e.g. `Set a = ActiveDocument` instead of `Set a = WordApp.ActiveDocument`) then VBA creates a hidden global variable to store which Application's ActiveDocument it refers to. Therefore if you try to quit that Application, you won't succeed and the Application will continue to run (without a visible window and without an error message) and the next time you want to refer to the ActiveDocument, it won't refer to the that Application's ActiveDocument which you started last time but the old Application's ActiveDocument, which, however was destroyed when the old Application started its process of exiting.

I examined your code and found no such unqualified reference.

My theory is that either (A) you judged some part of your code irrelevant to the problem and did not post it; and that contains such an unqualified reference; or (B) you are in the middle of developing this Sub and previous versions of the code created some dangling references.

In case (A) please post all other parts of your code that handles Outlook in any way.

In case (B) check in the Task Manager how many Outlook processes are running. Sign out from windows to make sure that all your Applications are closed, sign in, and try if the error still occurs.